# What's the preferred way of doing POST/GET using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, post, get, react-router

I have a simple route in React:

```
<Route path="/listUsers" exact component={UsersList} />
```

Different component (`navigation`) holds the link to the UsersList:

```
<Link to="/listUsers">All users</Link>
```

My back-end is very simple, once you make get request to /listUsers it responds with all the users, like:

```
app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
  UserModel.find({}, function(err, users) {
    res.send(users);
  })
})
```

I'm facing two problems here:

- **when do I actually make the request?** should I perform react's `fetch` on `componentDidMount` in `UsersList` component? or maybe on `componentWillMount`? so it will work like this - user clicks a link - I'm mounting component via react-router and at the same time - before/after mount performing fetch, does it make sense? I guess after fetching I should update the components internals somehow (possibly using `props`?),
- my node server is at `localhost:3000`, so I should be hitting `localhost:3000/listUsers`, yet my React app is being served by Apache at `localhost`, so the `<Link to="/listUsers">` actually points to a wrong URL, **I guess I'll be able to provide the proper URL within React's `fetch`**?

I know these are noobish questions but I'm sorry to say I found it very hard to make these clear to me and I'm not sure if https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html is the official React's documentation, because it's simply awful and it's next to impossible to find anything there.

Thank you so much.

Comment: for first question: do it in componentdidMount. If you store data in state, and later update the state, the UI will be changed automatically (if you use state in your UI).